# Which IdentityServer4 sample should I choose as a starting point?

Tags: azure, identityserver4

I am going to use identityServer4 to support a few clients.
There are many samples of server/host implementation and I'm not sure which one to chose as a starting point. Is any host maintained regularity and has the latest fixes?

- I have Asp.net core mvc and web.api clients(most of  IdentityServer4 samples included)
- I also have [Web forms Client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient)  for IdentityServer3 in VS2015
- I am using Azure Active Directory(AAD) and checked [sample](https://github.com/mclark1129/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/AzureAd_CustomStateDataFormat) that is a fork outside of IdentityServer repositories, but based on IdentityServer4 External Provider sample  in VS2015
- I want to use persistent data, so  I  looked at [IdentityServer4 EF Core Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage
  Sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage). If anyone has an example of Azure Table Storage or Redis implementation, please let me know?
- Also there is  Host in main [IdentityServer4 repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4). I assume that it has the most up-to-date code. But the default branch is dev- is it stable enough?

Should I take 8_EntityFrameworkStorage as the base( because it includes more of functionality that I need) or IdentityServer4 Host?
Or somewhere exists another recommended Host base implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I based my work on [Quickstart #8: EntityFramework configuration](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage) , but found that for user storage I need to incorporate Asp.Net Identity from [Quickstart #6: IdentityServer and ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity)
, which is quite  different ,in particular in AccountController ExternalLogin implementation.
Other people also struggled with merging different Quickstarts(e.g. [here](http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/) )

Later ( unfortunately a bit too late for myself) I found a brilliant article [Getting Started with IdentityServer 4](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)
 with corresponding source code repository https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example.
Note however that the repository is not a part of the official IdentityServer and may become out of date in the future.

I believe that **[Scott Brady's IdentityServer4-Example](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)** is the most practical start point for using IdentityServer4.

Comment: This example altought the logout does not work